# Why do I get a failure to get http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease when doing apt update on Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, packages

I have gone to install a new program, and when I have done an update I have received several warnings:

> W: Failed to get http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease Cannot start connection to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (2a04:4e42:4::644) . - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (151.101.18.132), timed out for connection Cannot start connection to deb.debian.org:80 ( 2a04:4e42:4::644). - connect (101: The network is inaccessible)

> W: Failed to get http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease Cannot start connection to deb.debian.org:80 (2a04:4e42:4::644). - connect (101: The network is inaccessible)

> W: Some index files could not be downloaded, were skipped, or used old ones instead.

````
In the /etc/apt/sources.list file I have the following:
```lang-sh
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.2.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20211218-11:13]/ bullseye contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.2.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20211218-11:13]/ bullseye contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security contrib non-free

# bullseye-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
# A network mirror was not selected during install. The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-fasttrack main contrib
deb https://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ bullseye-backports-staging main contrib
````

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server `debian.map.fastlydns.net` seems to be down for me too, which
explains your problem.

You should choose another mirror from the
[Debian worldwide mirror sites](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list).